# Change mobile-website background color via external admin or server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, websocket

Im looking for a way to change a background of a mobile-website via an external input. Let's say an admin which can change 'real-time' the background color of all other users which load the webpage. i.e. admin uses slider to control the color, other users see the color changing.

[image]

So i think i need three things.

- An admin based environment
- A server which gets the value of the background:color, and pushes it to the mobile-website.
- Mobile website loads the value of the server.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://demo.crossbar.io/colorpicker/index.html (and be sure to open this in two tabs at once). This basically does what you want. The software used is open source. (Disclaimer: I'm part of the team working on the software, but hey, it fits your needs.)

Explanation: 
Crossbar.io (http://crossbar.io) is a messaging router which connects components in distributed applications, using the WAMP protocol (http://wamp-proto.org). For components in the browser, the default protocol is WebSocket. WAMP has libraries for multiple programming languages, which can be mixed in an application.

All components can communicate using two messaging patterns: Publish & Subscribe and routed Remote Procedure Calls.

For a use case such as this, the controller page publishes color change events, and the mobile clients subscribe to these. Crossbar.io then distributes events to all subscribed clients.

Comment: Does this also work with a different mobile phone or multiple users at the same time? .. lets say. I'm on my Macbook changing the colors, and my two friends on their iPhone see the same changing colors? Nice to see this demo, let me dig into it!

Comment: How can i download the source-code and edit the main colorpicker, and place it on my webserver? I see it has some problems connecting and stuff. http://imgur.com/a/dOc5H

Comment: @Rowin -  This works for large numbers of users in parallel, and across any number of devices. The source code for the demo is at https://github.com/crossbario/crossbar-examples/tree/master/demos/colorpicker. You also need a WAMP router, e.g. http://crossbar.io - see installation instructions there (and also open source).

Comment: i totally new with WAMP etc. do i need a own server to host/install crossbar.io? If yes, what are the best options, and do website hosting also apply to this? (Still learning the whole abracadabra)

Comment: okay. just learned everything inside Heroku. Problem is that i cant install it the right way via Heroku CLI. Still getting the same problems with H10. Do you have a tutorial to install it the right way for the open source demo's? I still dont know what I'm doing wrong? @gzost

Comment: @rowin - I have no experience with Heroku. Does http://crossbar.io/docs/Setup-on-Heroku/ help? Once you've installed Crossbar.io, you can run the demo as is from the subdirectory in the examples repository. The necessary Crossbar.io config file is in there in the ".crossbar" directory.

Comment: yes everything works now! installation with Heroku was a problem with the "$port" thing, and just changed it in both config.json files. (.crossbar/config.json & color/config.json), add crossbar via terminal etc. and use the Heroku CLI.

Comment: Do you also have an idea how I can make something like this? - @gzost I want to test something, but how can I call the color? http://imgur.com/Rs5clKh